# How many different kinds of partitions of M coins for N players?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Ex: 7 coins, 7 players, players and coins are indistinguishable. There are 15 kinds of partitions:

```
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
(2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0)
(3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
(3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
(3, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(4, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
(4, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(4, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(5, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

They are generated by a simple recursive program. For large coins and players, it can only enumerate partitions one by one, rather than tell me the total size. Is there a way to directly compute how many kinds of partitions it has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well studied problem in combinatorics and the name *is* in fact [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).

There is no simple closed form, but there are some recurrence relations, and perhaps more interestingly a generating function as well as asymptotic estimates.
We have:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n\geq 0}\,p(n)\,x^n
&=
\prod_{k\geq 1}\,\left(\frac1{1-x^k}\right)
\\&=
(1+x+^2+x^3+\dots)\,(1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\dots)\,(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\dots)\cdots
\end{align}

and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac1{4n\sqrt3}\,\exp\left(\pi\sqrt{\frac{2n}3}\right)}{p(n)} = 1.$$

Comment: Thank you for pointing out there is no closed form. However, my question is a little different that the number of slots is fixed. So the number of partitions is less than full integer partition. eg. 9 coins 3 players. I found "Restricted part size or number of parts" is related.

Comment: My bad, but glad to have been of help in any case!